# how to load jars in directory on execute

Tags: java

*(Read the bold text for the very short version of my question)*

I am currently writing an music indexer that watches a folder for any added files and will parse those files when found.

My idea was to create some kind of mediator system for events and have other jars hook into those events (ie: "pre_index") and have their code executed too (and possibly if required cancel further execution, ie: when an exception or error occurs).

In order to easily add extra functionality to this plugin, and when distributed allow others to easily configure the indexer with required extra functionality for themselfes **I want to load any extra modules (jars) from a directory when my main jar gets executed**.

From what I've read so far on different websites and some stackoverflow pages is that this seems to be really hard to do as classloaders aren't meant for this to happen, the main factor beeing security.

I've learned most of my Java knowledge from writing mods in Bukkit (Minecraft Server project, discontinued) and they have got this system working (seemingly) fine.

**So basically my question is**, how did Bukkit achieve this, and how can I replicate something similar (or basic) that won't cause any memoryleaks or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Focus on modules or packages instead of jars.**

Code organization is the first step.  You do not need to worry about how to organize and deploy your jar files until this is done.  So first of all, focus on that.

To that extent, use packages and pay attention to package-level dependencies.  It is very appropriate to break your code into multiple packages.  Each package should solve unique sets of problems with common functionality and theme.  Packages should always have one-way dependencies so you can organize them in a dependency tree.  This is fundamental to good design of large systems.

For your design, it sounds great to have a package which only handles the monitoring of a folder.  Create a monitor object which scans the folder and calls back to a listener interface to notify when files are created or changed.  Wrap up and test this package by itself, using some sort of dummy listener that just logs the file changes so you can test this package.

Once you have this package, you can use this as you would any other library.  Instantiate the monitor object with your target directory.  Implement the listener interface with a handler that will parse the file and extract the appropriate data. Add that listener to the monitor object to be called when a file is added or changed.

Once you have this completed and working, then you can worry about how you will deploy it.  You can then deploy the monitor package as its own jar if you like.

Thinking this way is required when working on really large projects.  Breaking the code into packages with a dependency tree is one of the first steps.  This allows the team to focus on creating the base packages first which don't have any dependencies.  If work will be done simultaneously on packages which depend on other packages under development, those developers will know who to coordinate with for which pieces.

When working on smaller projects, this method still helps keep your code organized and reusable.

Comment: it doesn't really answer the question from a literal viewpoint, but I appreciate  the information and will thus accept it as the answer, thanks

Comment: Literally to include a jar you just have to add it to your classpath in the command line. I'm sure there are other questions that address that angle.